# broadcast receiver not receiving intent from service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have searched SO and even found a question with more or less the same title as my question. But still my code isn't working.

I try to send a position from my GPS service to my MainActivity using broadcast.

In my GPS service I do

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.EXTRA_NEW_POS_FOR_PLOTTING_INTENT);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NEW_POS_FOR_PLOTTING, new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

On the receiving side in MainActivity.onCreate() i do:

```
mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                LatLng pos = intent.getExtras().getParcelable(EXTRA_NEW_POS_FOR_PLOTTING);
                newLocForPlotting(pos);
            }
        };
```

And in MainActivity.onStart() I have:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(EXTRA_NEW_POS_FOR_PLOTTING_INTENT ));
```

I know that my service calls sendBroadcast(), but my onReceive() is never called.

What is going wrong?

Comment: put your Activity.onStart() mehtod code into Activity.onResume()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code into your activity onResume method.

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(EXTRA_NEW_POS_FOR_PLOTTING_INTENT ));
```

You can also use Local broadcast like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BundleTags.BROADCAST_TAG_FOR_INCOMING_CALL_REQUEST);
            // You can also include some extra data.
            intent.putExtra(RESPONSE_MESSAGE, body);

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In activity

```
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ServiceProviderActivity.this).registerReceiver(myReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_TAG_FOR_INCOMING_CALL_REQUEST));
```

Comment: putting registerReceiver in onResume seems to do the trick.  Do you know why it can't be in onStart, as I have seen it done in many sources?

Comment: yes, but I wonder if you have an answer to my follow-up question

Comment: actually i dont know your implementation but according to my understanding your onstart was not calling in some scenarios

Comment: If your activity is running and you pause the application then onstart will not call only onresume will call.

Comment: Now I found the root cause. When starting up attached to Android Studio, my app was doing onStart(), then onResume(), then within 20mSec onPause()/ onResume() (for whatever reason). And here it comes: I had my unregisterReceiver in onPause().. So you must of course either register/ deregister in onResume()/onPause() or in onStart()/onStop(). .. obviously